# selectively retrieve message from the queue using correlation_id

Tags: python, rabbitmq

In Rabbitmq I have a queue "aggregator" bind to exchange "Exhange1" with routing key "agg.*". Messages are published to this queue with dynamically generator `correlation_id`. Let's say message with `correlation_id='1234'` is published to this exchange & consumer wants to consume only this particular message without consuming other message & sending back until I get `correlation_id=1234`.Is there a way to achieve this?

This question is not regarding segregating messages based on routing key

Basically I want to apply `correlation_id` as a filter and consume the specific message without consuming all messages because Rabbitmq doc says its antipattern.

Answer (score 0):

RabbitMQ delivers messages in FIFO order. There is no way to de-queue a specific message.

Topic exchanges may address your use-case. Don't forget that it's perfectly fine for consumers to bind to exchanges with their own exclusive queues, using whatever binding parameters are appropriate for the use-case.